# Create a Custom ImageButton Class with FrameLayout and TextView

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie, so, any help is appreciated. I read a lot of posts here at StackOverflow and also I searched for my doubt in Google, but it's hard to find a good answer.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">    
    <ImageButton 
        android:background="@layout/roundcorners" 
        android:id="@+id/hug" 
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hug">
    </ImageButton>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:text="Hug">
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Above you guys can see the XML version of what I need.**

The point is... I will have many of these FrameLayouts at run time. Every information to fill out the buttons will come from a database.

So, I need to create a Java Class where I can use a loop through all the registers from my database and instantiate a new FrameLayout Class (this class must have an ImageButton and a TextView as you can see from above XML) and just pass parameters, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; i++) {
        button = new MyNewImageButton(name, src, text);
}
```

The above is just to simplify. What I mean is that I will pass parameters from my database when creating an Instance of this class that I am planning to create. Of course, every single button created will be added to the layout.

**So... my question is: I know how to do this using XML, but I am REALLY having a hard time to create a class to do this.**

**Any thoughts? Any help is appreciated.**

P.S.: Sorry if I made any mistake in my English, ok? I am a Brazilian. Someday my English will be flawless! Sorry if this question was already answered.

---

sorry to answer my own question to make another question. I tried to use the comments but there's a limitation in the number of characters, so, I am really sorry.

Hey guys and @blessenm. Well... I tried to use inflater and I came up with the following code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    // ******************************************* 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      


    //this is my main screen
    //it's a linearlayout vertical orientation
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.tela_principal);

    //these two new LinearLayouts will be one above the other, 
    //just like two lines
    LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(this);

    //inside of each linearlayout I set the orientation to horizontal
    //so, everytime a picture is inflated from xml, it will fill in one
    //linearlayout
    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    //setting linearlayout parameters, so they fill the whole screen
    l1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    l2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


    //the first two inflated xml imagebuttons I add to LinearView1
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.figurabotao,
            l1, true);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.figurabotao,
            l1, true);

    //the next two inflated xml imagebuttons I add to LinearView2
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.figurabotao,
            l2, true);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.figurabotao,
            l2, true);

    //after the above, we should have a grid 2X2


    //after linearlayouts are filled, I add them to the main screen
    parent.addView(l1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 1));
    parent.addView(l2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 1));
```

However this is not working. In the errorlog I get the following message:

"Unhandled event loop exception".

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to create a view from the xml and add it to the layout. Just use the LayoutInflater.

Inside the activity use something like

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)getLayoutInfalter.inflate(
        R.id.YOUR_VIEW_XML,null);
layout.addView(frame);
```

If you are trying to create a class extend the frame layout or the the view. Create a constructor which takes your parameters and assign's the required values.

EDIT:
To Acess Elements Inside
If you have set id's to those element, you can access them by

```
TextView text = (TextView)frame.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
```

Or you can use the child index like

```
TextView text = (TextView)frame.getChildAt(0);
```

Comment: Hello Blessenm, yes, your suggestion worked, thanks. *HOWEVER*, how do I refer to each element inside the inflated XML? I mean, I will need to have a reference to the ImageButton and to the TextView so I can set them with the values from the database. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to create a view class that will be an ImageButton and a TextView wrapped with a FrameLayout.

In this case, you could look into creating your own View class.  Probably a View class that extends FrameLayout.  See this dev article for more information about how to create a custom view.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Specifically the "Compound Controls" section: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound